# Spreading UV light? Fresnel lenses?

Tags: visible-light, diffraction, wavelength, lenses

I'm making a little UV exposure box and I'm looking for a way to evenly spread out the UV light.

I've used Fresnel lenses to do just this in the past, but that was for visible light. But from what I've read, not all things work at all wavelengths and some materials will block UV.

So my first question, would a Fresnel lens still work and evenly spread out UV light?

What material should I look for? The lens I've seen are PVC and from what I've seen elsewhere, PVC has good UV resistance, but I don't know if that means it will just hold up to UV or if it will block UV all together.

Any tips or suggestions would be great thank you

Comment: I assume you are referring to UV diffraction?

Comment: It depends on what kind of UV you're talking about. Usually when clear PVC products claim to have "good UV resistance", they mean to say that they absorb short-wave UV so that it can't pass through. I'm not sure about long-wave UV though, so you may want to contact the manufacturer for a UV-Vis spectrum. Most optical glass transmits long-wave UV, and fused silica transmits long and short-wave UV.